# How can I get an executable's icon in .Net?

Tags: .net, windows, icons

I'm looking to get an executable's application icon in .Net. How can I do this? I'm thinking I'll have to query its resources, some how, but I'm open to any general-case solution.

Comment: Is this from another application?

Comment: Yes. I want to retrieve the icon of an executable via its path from the app I'm writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a hard-path:

```
Icon ico = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);
```

From a resource dll:

```
// Process handle
IntPtr processHandle  = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;

// DLL path
string DLLPath = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "shell32.dll");

// Open folder icon index
int iconIndex         = 4; 

// Extract icon
System.IntPtr oPtr = ExtractIcon(processHandle, DLLPath, iconIndex);

Icon oIcon = Icon.FromHandle(oPtr);
```

From:

[C# Extract icons and system icons](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/extract-icon.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work. It also pulls the icon for other file types (i.e. a white sheet of paper for .txt), though it will not pull embedded thumbnails (since those are injected by shell extensions).

`icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filename);`